# OpenGL Alpha values having no effect in shader

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, fragment-shader

I have a simple shader to make scanlines in my 2d game which works fine and is as follows:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
    vec2 p = vec2(floor(gl_FragCoord.x), floor(gl_FragCoord.y));
    if (mod(p.y, 6.0)==0.0)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.1);
    else
        gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
}
```

But if I change the alpha value in the vec4 for the fragment colour, it has no effect, the scanlines are equally black at 0.1 as they are at 1.0. I saw some other questions regarding this which advised to enable blending, but I tried that to no avail.

This is my render method with blending enabled.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    // batch.enableBlending(); tried this too but no effect
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.setShader(shaderProgram);
    batch.begin();
    rendup.renderAll(batch);//renders all sprites, tiles etc
    batch.setShader(null);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: `glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND)` and `glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` have zero effect on SpriteBatch because SpriteBatch manages its blending internally. Use the SpriteBatch methods for enabling blending and setting blend function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a blending problem. The issue is your shader only draws either a translucent black pixel, or the color of whatever texture region is being drawn. These black pixels are just getting blended with what's already on the screen (in this case the black clear color).

I assume what you actually want here is for the scan lines not to be pure black. So you should be drawing the color of the texture region everywhere, and just darken it slightly where the scan lines are. You don't want to be modifying the alpha that the shader outputs, or when you have overlapping sprites, the scanline will appear darker in that area.

So change your shader like this:

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

const float DARK_LINE_BRIGHTNESS = 0.9;

void main() {
    vec4 color = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    vec2 p = vec2(floor(gl_FragCoord.x), floor(gl_FragCoord.y));
    if (mod(p.y, 6.0)==0.0)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb * DARK_LINE_BRIGHTNESS, color.a);
    else
        gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

However, `if`/`else` should be avoided in fragment shaders because it performs significantly worse in most cases. (Exception is if the `if` statement evaluates to the same value for many pixels in a row, such as with `if (u_someUniformBoolean)`.) You could rewrite it like this:

```c
void main() {
    vec4 color = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    vec2 p = vec2(floor(gl_FragCoord.x), floor(gl_FragCoord.y));
    gl_FragColor = (step(0.01, mod(p.y, 6.0)) * (1.0 - DARK_LINE_BRIGHTNESS) + DARK_LINE_BRIGHTNESS) * color;
}
```

Comment: That's not transparency though, that's just darkness of the lines. I want some of the graphics underneath the scan lines to show through. I already tried a lighter colour but it didn't look any better. Is there no way to draw these scan lines actually over the top of the graphics? I did it originally with a simple texture drawn over the top but it's not so performant as a shader.

Comment: Are you using this shader to draw all the sprites, to draw scan lines over everything that's already been drawn to screen, or to draw a frame buffer texture with all the sprites to the screen? I was assuming the first one.

Comment: I'm using the shader to draw all the sprites and tiles, no frame buffer. Also when I used a texture drawn on screen I was able to alter the thickness of the scan lines, but I can't see how to do it with a shader, only alter the distance between the lines.

Comment: If you're using the shader to draw every individual item, I can't see how transparency would be what you want. Everything that aligns with a scan line would appear translucent. Did you try the above? And to adjust thickness of those lines, check if  the result of `mod` is less than some number smaller than the 6.0 instead of exact 0.0. With the `step` function like in my second example, set the step value to some value between 0 and 6 to adjust thickness. And adjust 6 to adjust spacing.

Comment: Ok now I adjusted the thickness it does look pretty good actually.

Comment: Yes I managed to do it without the if else so just deleted my other comment. Thanks for your help, it looks perfect now after some adjustments. :) You can tell I'm brand new to shaders.